# Property of the Set

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb R$, satisfying $A \neq \emptyset$ and $A \neq \mathbb R$. Then $A$ is

1. the closure of the interior of $A$.
2. a countable set.
3. a compact set.
4. not open.

> Argument:

Since, $A$ is  subset of $\mathbb R$, it should be an interval or singleton set.

$A$ cannot be countable. counter example is $[0,1]$ so (2) is not the answer.

$A \neq cl(int(A))$. counter example any singleton set $A={1}$. $int(A) = \phi$

$cl(int(A)) = \phi \neq A$.(Hence (1) is not the answer)

Definitely $A$ is not open (whole set and empty set are only sets which are both open and closed) but what about Compactness, Since $A$ is already closed, if it is bounded, then it is compact. Since any subset of $\mathbb R$ is of $[-a,b]$ which is bounded, hence $A$ is compact and $A$ is also not open.

Am i right? or please indicate where my argument is wrong..

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ does not have to be an interval or a singleton. What about $A=\{1\}\cup[2,3]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wording is confusing. For example, you use "cannot" where
you mean "is not necessarily:"

1. $A$ is not necessarily the closure of its interior; consider $A=\{0\}$.
2. $A$ is not necessarily countable; consider $A=[0,1]$.
3. $A$ is not necessarily compact; consider $A=\mathbb{N}$.
4. Suppose $A$ is open. Since $A\neq\emptyset$ and $A\neq\mathbb{R}$,
   it follows that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a [connected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space); a contradiction.
   Therefore, $A$ is not open.

I would work on your mathematical writing. Compare the above with your answers and see where they differ.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. sure i will work on my mathematical writing.

Answer (score 1):

1. False, take a singleton for instance
2. Not necessarily, take any closed interval.
3. False, take $[1,+\infty[$ for instance
4. True, since $\mathbb R$, the only subset that is both closed and open is $\mathbb R$ itself.

---

As pointed out in the comments, you are wrong to assert that A can only be a singleton or an interval, it can also be any finite union of both.

Comment: Yes not necessarily. But we are sure by definition that any finite union of closed subset is itself closed. That was a non-exclusive sentence ;)